# Driverless printing w IPP on Brother HL-L2350DW from 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing, brother, cups-lpd

The Brother HL-L2350DW is designed to work with smart phones and I'm able to print from it on my Pixel 7 out of the box. Was wondering if it is possible to take advantage of this wireless printing interface (IPP) that is used on our phones from a ubuntu desktop environment. Seems like it should not be too hard.

There are threads suggest they got basic printing to work in Linux on amazon's site. Here is a response from DB87.

> Out of the box, I was able to successfully install drivers and wirelessly print from two Mac 10.10 and 10.11 devices in my house. However, attempting to set up Google Cloud Print was met with repeat failure. I was also unable to install the printer wirelessly on my Linux desktop (Manjaro 4.19.13). I attempted to register Google Cloud Print from the settings menu of Chrome browsers on Mac, Linux, and Windows. I also tried through the Brother web interface. If you are continually being asked to press OK for registration, and being met with an "Unable to Connect to Google. Please check your network" error message, you need to update the firmware.
> Once updated, both my Google Cloud Print and Linux driver problems disappeared. For Manjaro, I am using the brother-hll2350dw driver v4.0.0-1 from the AUR. For Google Cloud Print, you need to log in via the IP of your printer (default password is "initpass"), go to Network > Protocol and click on 'Advanced Settings' for Google Cloud Print, and follow the instructions for registering. I was lucky to have a computer successfully connect out of the box in order to update the firmware. If you don't have a computer that can connect without the firmware update, I'm not sure how you will be able to update the firmware. Maybe connecting directly over USB will circumvent the connection issues.
> As far as printing goes, it's a cheap, fast, monochrome laser printer. It does everything I need, and seems well built. This is a five-star printer except for the connection issues and requiring a firmware update right out the box, which knocks it to a 4-star in my book.

Output suggested by @brian_p

```
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ lpstat -l -e
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series network none ipp://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
Brother_MFC_L2740DW_series network none ipp://Brother%20MFC-L2740DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
CUPS-BRF-Printer-HL permanent ipp://localhost/printers/CUPS-BRF-Printer-HL cups-brf:/
CUPS-BRF-Printer-MFC permanent ipp://localhost/printers/CUPS-BRF-Printer-MFC cups-brf:/
```

Note when I use the Settings > Printers section to add a printer after I've turned on wifi I get a Failed to add new printer dialog.

I have two IPP printers btw which i can print to easily from my pixel 7. When i search for printers on ubuntu os it appears to find them but give me an error while trying to find the drivers for them. Bummer. I will attach a screen shot.

[image: screen shot of detecting my brother IPP printers]

[image: unable to find suitable driver]

I ran the following commands and the test print command gave me Destination is not accepting jobs.

```
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ systemctl stop cups-browsed
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ sudo apt purge cups-browsed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cups-browsed*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
After this operation, 387 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 236183 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cups-browsed (1.28.15-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
(Reading database ... 236171 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for cups-browsed (1.28.15-0ubuntu1.2) ...
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ lpstat -l -e
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series network none ipp://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /etc/nsswitch.conf
lp: Destination "Brother_HL_L2350DW_series" is not accepting jobs.
```

adding test with the queue:

```
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ lpadmin -p L2350DW -v "ipp://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/" -E -m everywhere
james@james-NUC7i5DNHE:~$ lp -d L2350DW /etc/nsswitch.conf
request id is L2350DW-15 (1 file(s))
```

so the error feedback come via a GUI popup:
[image]

Comment: Do you have WiFi on your computer? Does your WiFi network allow unencrypted access? That's what printers seem to want. Point your browser to `http://localhost:631`, the management interface for CUPS (Common Unix Printing System). If you can wirelessly `ping` the printer, click on `Add Printer`.

Comment: Give the output of `lpstat -l -e`.

Comment: A quickish rant: DBD7 starts off with `Out of the box, I was able to successfully install drivers...`. Installing vendor drivers?  Why use vendor drivers? Ubuntu is a driverless printing system. Many users follow DBD's advice and end up in quagmire. The pixel 7 knpws that vendor drivers are not needed. So does Ubuntu's printing system. But users think vendor drivers are the bee's knees and drop themselves in the mire. localhost:631 is not the answer.

Comment: Driverless sounds like the right solution to me. I hear IPP is what is used for phones so seems it should be something that can be implemented on any OS like Ubuntu. Does anyone know how I can set this up? I'm assuming IPP handles dynamic IP address so I don't have to worry about broken URLs.

Comment: @brian_p i added the output of lpstat -l -e. it might have printers i've added previously but they don't seem to work.

Comment: The netflix event is not relevant, just left it in so you could see the context being Gnome Desktop is showing the error event. It's the second one that indicates the printer is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Gnome, so I failrf to follow. I also do not understand the failure of two queue setup techniques. Buggy printer firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually emailed brother support who made me are of the CUPS web configuration utility. Turns out we can configure CUPS to do IPP printing wo needing to enter the printer's IP address which is most ideal because the printer's IP can change when the printer leaves and rejoins the network. Printer works great now!

Steps I used to add printer:

1. go to localhost:631/printers (might need to log in)
2. Select Administration tab
3. Under Printers select "Add Printer"
4. It displayed my two brother's:

   - Brother HL-L2350DW series (driverless) (Brother HL-L2350DW series)
   - Brother MFC-L2740DW series (driverless) (Brother MFC-L2740DW series)
5. Select your printer
6. Select Continue[image]
7. Select the model [image]
8. Select "Add Printer"

Printer should be added, can print a test page.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

CUPS and the Pixel 7 detect the printer as

```
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series
```

and as having a URI of

```
ipp://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
```

Therefore, both know the printer name and where it is.

Stop cups-browsed with `systenctl stop cups-browsed`. It isn't needed by CUPS and the Pixel 7 doesn't use it. Should what follows work (and it should), I would advise `apt purge cups-browsed`.

Check that the printer is still enumerated by `lpstat -l -e`. It should show in the print dialogs of applications such as Firefox. Do a quick test of printing with

```
lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

A **permanent** queue may be set up with

```
lpadmin -p L2350DW -v "URI" -E -m everywhere
```

substituting for URI from above, of course. Test with `lp -d L2350DW /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: I updated description with the suggested commands and when doing the test print got the response: ,lp: Destination "Brother_HL_L2350DW_series" is not accepting jobs., Is there something else I need to do first?

Comment: *Destination is not accepting jobs* should not happen. How does using the suggested permanent queue work out?

Comment: Did the queue test and added results to description.

Comment: I am completely and utterly flummoxed by this latest response! How does Netfix get into the act?